# Can I change misleading content in an answer if the OP is no longer an active user?

Tags: discussion

Normally when I spot some sort of incongruity, falsehood, or misleading content in an answer I will leave a comment to notify the OP, and wait for them to make the change. From what I've heard, this is the Stack Exchange convention (and it seems like good etiquette to me not to go putting words in someone else's mouth).

But I've found a case ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106614/1291990)) where part of an answer is slightly misleading, and I would like to change it. I was going to leave a comment, but I checked the OP's profile to see if they were still active, and sure enough they haven't been seen for over 5 years (since `Jun 11 '09 at 5:21`), so it seems unlikely that they will ever return to edit the post.

I wouldn't be so worried about it, but the post in question is extremely popular, and I (a fallible human being) do not want to go messing up a post that so many people have found helpful.

What do I do?

Comment: I'd leave a comment.

Comment: Like @JayBlanchard said, leave a comment. Bookmark the page/favorite the question. Return in one week, if no edit/no answer, edit it. That's how I'd handle it.

Comment: No, never mess with an answer that 565 users found helpful.  The unthinkable might apply, you *could* actually, really, be wrong about your interpretation of it.  Post your own answer.  If it more truthy than the accepted answer then it will rise to the top, eventually.

Comment: The more votes a post has, the more care must be taken when changing it. While editing is still allowed to polish the answer, the risk of being wrong is probably too high (especially as the original poster won't see any change). At least, make sure to get some high-rep eyes on it to review your change. Still, are you really sure adding another answer is not the appropriate course of action?

Comment: @Deduplicator The answer in question is **really** good in my opinion, and I don't think I could write a better one (except for the part I want to remove). I could copy the text of the answer, or restate it line by line, but that just seems like plagiarism.

Comment: @Deduplicator How could I go about "get[ting] some high-rep eyes on it"?

Comment: What do you want to change there? And you might ask in chat, though your reception really depends on how you ask.

Comment: @HansPassant: You know, even answers with a vote-balance over 100 are not even immune from removal. Also, editing to improve the content, especially on the questions and answers in the spotlight, is official policy (and might happen too little due to the danger to slip and make a hash of things). Anyway, all edits are part of the permanent record and can thus be rolled back if needed. Final comment: Take a look at that answers revision history and compare with the last time the creator visited; Should none of those revisions have happened?

Comment: The proper course is to post your own answer. Modifying the user's existing answer to significantly different content is wrong, and you're risking their reputation (and possibly their account status) by changing it. If a new answer isn't appropriate, leave a comment instead and leave the answer alone. Whether the person who answered is currently active or not is irrelevant.

Comment: All of these are good answers. Why is nobody posting them as answers?